# why is else if function is not working in rock, paper, scissor?

Tags: c++

I was asked to make a simple game of rock, paper, scissors in C++ but it turns out that my `else if` logic is not working. What do you think went wrong?

```cpp
cout << "choose your pick..." << endl;
cout << "PRESS [ B ] if BATO(ROCK),[ G ] if GUNTING(SCISSOR) or [ P ] if PAPEL(PAPER) " << endl;

cin >> pick;
cin >> picke;

if (   (pick==picke) || (pick=='b' && picke=='B')
    || (pick=='B' && picke=='b') || (pick=='g' && picke=='G')
    || (pick=='G' && picke=='g') || (pick=='p' && picke=='P'))
{
    cout << "SORRY TIE";
}
else if (pick=='p' || 'P' && pic­ke=='b' || 'B')
{
    cout << "player 1 paper wins";
}
else if (pick=='b' || 'B' && pic­ke=='g' || 'G')
{
    cout << "player 1 rocks wins";
}
else if (pick=='g' || 'G' && pic­ke=='p' || 'P')
{
    cout << "player 1 scissor wins";
}
else if (pick=='b' || 'B' && pic­ke=='p' || 'P')
{
    cout << "player 2 paper wins";
}
else if (pick=='g' || 'G' && pic­ke=='b' || 'B')
{
    cout << "player 2 rocks wins";
}
else if (pick=='p' || 'P' && pic­ke=='g' || 'G')
{
    cout << "player 2 scissor wins";
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Please show how `pick` and `picke` are declared. Parts like `pick=='b'||'B'` probably are not doing what you want. Maybe they should be converted to `pick == 'b' || pick == 'B'`. Same for `picke`

Comment: You can use `tolower` to convert a `char` to lowercase, then you don't have to think about so many possibilities.

Comment: The logical connectives go between expression that are true or false. "A equals B or C" translated from English into C++ logic is `A == B || A == C`. `A == B || C` means "A equals B, or C is truthy".

Answer (score 2):

Comparing like this: `pick=='p' || 'P' && pic­ke=='b' || 'B'` is pretty much useless. This is because the if statements condition will always be true. Why? Let me explain.

You cannot compare and check if `pick` contains either `'p'` or `'P'` like that. It sounds right in words but in C++ it is wrong. This is because in programming terms, it's like "is `pick` equal to `'p'` OR is 'pick' equal to `'P'`". You need to tell the compiler that you're checking if "is this equal to this". Not "is this equal to this and this" (like what you have right there).

If you have something like `... || 'p' && ...`, it'll always be true, because the value of `'p'` is not `0`, meaning its true in boolean terms.

So to resolve this, we need to say "is `pick` equal to 'this'" every time we compare. So it may look like this,

```cpp
//...
else if ((pick == 'p'|| pick == 'P') && (pic­ke == 'b'|| picke == 'B'))
{
    cout << "player 1 paper wins";
}
else if ((pick == 'b'|| pick == 'B') && (pic­ke == 'g'|| picke == 'G'))
//...
```

Or else you can use [`tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) or [`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) as @mch commented, to convert all the characters to a single case. It'll be easier and more efficient when comparing.

Note: It's better if you use brackets to segment the comparisons because it will not only will be easier to understand, it'll be correct logically too.